# Find number of strings consists in column

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to count how many strings are present compared to from other column.
df

```
year = c(2020,2020,2021,2021)
name = c("Michel","Doron","Neil sean","jack")
name_1 = c("ch","2b","sn b","akcj")

df = data.frame(year,name,name_1)
```

And my output column should return how many characters are matching from name_1 column to the name column.Below is the output column

```
df$output = c(2,0,3,4)
```

for ex: row-1 from name_1 column having ch i.e both c and h strings are present in name column.
in row-4 all a k c j are present in name column

I have tried with str_count from stringr package but not getting desired ouput.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_count` as -

```
df$output <- stringr::str_count(df$name, sprintf('[%s]', df$name_1))
df$output
#[1] 2 0 3 4
```

Another approach is to split the string and count the ones that match.

```
df$output <- mapply(function(x, y) sum(x %in% y), 
       strsplit(df$name, ''), strsplit(df$name_1, ''))

df$output 
#[1] 2 0 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(output = map2(name, name_1, function(a, b) {
            map_dbl(strsplit(b, "")[[1]], 
                     ~ grepl(.x, a)) %>% sum()
         }))

  year      name name_1 output
1 2020    Michel     ch      2
2 2020     Doron     2b      0
3 2021 Neil sean   sn b      3
4 2021      jack   akcj      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Uisng `glue`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(df$name, glue::glue("[{df$name_1}]"))
[1] 2 0 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what it looks like if you (like me) did not know @ronak shah's trick with `sprintf()`

```
result<-vector()
for (i in seq_along(df[,3])){
  count<-0
  for(j in 1:nchar(df[,3][i])){
    count <- c(count, str_count(df[,2][i], str_sub(df[,3][i], j, j)))
  }
  result<-c(result, sum(count))
}
df$output<-result

df
  year      name name_1 output
1 2020    Michel     ch      2
2 2020     Doron     2b      0
3 2021 Neil sean   sn b      3
4 2021      jack   akcj      4
```